# $LU$ factorization to solve a system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

I am having trouble solving the following exercise:

> Suppose $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ has an $LU$ factorization. Show how $Ax=b$ can be solved without storing the multipliers by computing the $LU$ factorization of the $n-\text{by}-(n+1)$ matrix $[A\ \ b]$

The problem I have is that so far to solve this it is usually done with the Gaussian elimination methods, where multipliers are used and in the same algorithm there is a part that specifically stores the multipliers ($\tau_i=\frac{v_i}{v_k}$ those used in Gaussian elimination), so I don't know how It is possible to define solving the system without storing the multipliers, since from what I have seen so far, for this type of problems we use Gaussian transformations, but these in their development use multipliers, in the case of obtaining the factorization of the Augmented matrix I also have doubts about why it is possible to obtain it, since what I know is that a matrix has LU factorization only when it is non-singular and then what would be the criteria to determine whether or not it has LU factorization (using the lu command in MatLab I have experimented with some systems and when I put matrices for example for a $2x2$ system and I try to obtain the $LU$ factorization if it throws it at me), I think that I don't understand the operation even of the $LU$ factorization.

I am using the Golub matrix computations book to study this topic and it is one of the proposed exercises. Well, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588135/benefits-of-lu-factorization) I have read about the benefits of using LU in these cases

Any help you can give me I appreciate a lot in advance, thank you.

Comment: If we are to use the $LU$ factorization, the multipliers are stored in the entries of $L$, so I suppose the question may be "vague" as to what is understood as not storing the multipliers.

Comment: @PierreCarre Thanks for your contribution

Comment: The multipliers are required to define the lower triangular matrix $L$. Are you sure the question isn't about storing multipliers *without performing matrix multiplication*?

Comment: @xXACEXx I'm sure, copy the statement as it was in the Golub

Comment: Well if that's the case then I am curious to know how it will be soled.

Comment: Yes, it seems to me an interesting problem, I hope someone posts the answer or if I can solve it, I post the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$L[U, u_b]=[A,b]$$

We have $A=LU$, $b=Lu_b$.

$Ax=b$ is equivalent to $LUx = Lu_b$.
If $L$ is invertible, then

$$Ux=u_b$$

We just need to know $L$ is invertible and we do not need to store it. To solve it, we just perform backward substitution.

Comment: you are absolutely right, thank you!

Comment: $(+1)$ Nice solution

Comment: @Siong Thye Goh, excuse me, could you help me with this please: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4108647/about-condition-number